# Programming Need for Developing a common portal accessible to various users using Microsoft SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ms-project

I want to design a web based portal which would be used for Project Monitoring. Basically its my Masters degree Project and I am completely unaware of any of programming languages as I never came across any of them till date. I want to ask can i design such portal using Microsoft SharePoint without any Programming? And if programming is needed what kind of programming should I Learn. I want to link MS Project on that Portal as well. Please Help. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very big question(s) and a potentially a very big undertaking. Just so you know I would not even attempt such a thing without at least 2 - 3 people. There is just a lot to do. But, it's all about what you need and how much time you have. Maybe what you need for your project can be done with a collection of stock solutions.

I would take a look at what can be done on Office 365 / Project Online. Maybe you can leverage some of the starters they have. Maybe with a little tweaking they will meet your needs.

You are going to need Project Online, in my opinion. Project Online is basically the cloud incarnation of Project Server. It is coupled with SharePoint. Project Online has a good deal of built in reporting and you can expose a good deal of MS Project content in SharePoint.

Can you do it with no programming? That's going to depend on what you want. I suspect that for a masters project, which to me is basically a proof of concept, yes you probably can. Microsoft has done a lot in the past couple of years to enable out of the box solutions with "configuration only" via the administrative UIs.

That said, it's not a slam dunk. There is A LOT to learn. There can be A LOT to do.

If programming is needed you could be getting into several languages very fast. C#, Visual Basic, JavaScript, Transact SQL, and of course HTML & CSS are the biggies.

I'd avoid the programming route or find someone to help who has some programming experience.

So check out Office 365 & Project Online within that. I believe they have free student accounts but I am not sure.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solid explanation. I am pursuing internship at Die Casting Foundry. My internship work will be considered as my Masters Degree Project. Currently company has MS Project. But its not MS Project online or MS Project Server. Even they are not having the MS SharePoint. I need to present a presentation in which I am gonna explain them about the feasibility and methodology for this Project Monitoring Systems Idea. So I need to be very clear and precise while giving that presentation. Thanks a lot. Your answer will definitely help me. Any further suggestions..??